# required query for Cosmosdb timestamp calculation

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-logic-apps

My cosmosdb is updated daily with some data , which looks like

```
{
    "Price": {
        "For": "9070.040",
        "From": "700.990"
    },
    "ArticleNumber": "71151004",
    "ArticleNumberPartitionKey": "7115",
    "ForStatus": "ACTIVE",
    "id": "71151004",
    "_rid": "ky1XAMpBiEoDAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/ky1XAA==/colls/ky1XAMpBiEo=/docs/ky1XAMpBiEoDAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"1200f241-0000-0d00-0000-60c8dad00000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1623775952
}
```

My logic is setup with recurrance of 24 hrs. My issue is I am unable to get the data for last 24 hrs if any new data gets added in the cosmosdb. I would like to use "_ts" to get the data for last 24 horurs only. Any idea how to do that?

tried with this but not getting the required result.

```
Int32 unixTimestamp = (Int32)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
```

Comment: Have you tried something that isn't working? `_ts` is a Unix timestamp and 24 hours ago is easily calculated in most languages

Comment: edited the question with the one which I tried.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET the following will get the unix time 24 hours ago:

```
long hoursAgo24 = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(-24).ToUnixTimeSeconds();
```

With that value you should be able to run a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM c
WHERE c._ts > @hoursAgo24
```

Comment: DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(-24).ToUnixTimeSeconds();
this showing invalid in logic apps

Comment: Ah, I didn't see your question mention logic apps. You'd have to use the built-in functions to get the value.